# Logback - Print classname

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-classic

I am using logback but,
rather than having the logger class called directly,
I would like to have a custom class/wrapper class which logs the data.
(This is required by the usecase).
I would like to print the source class names which are calling this wrapper 
class rather than the wrapper class.
I tried logging with this class but its always printing the className of the wrapper class.

```
class MyAppLogTest {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    String msg="Some Msg";
    ApplicationLogger.logData( "MyAppLogTest", "main",msg);
    }
}


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class ApplicationLogger {

private static Logger logger = null;

    static {
        logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationLogger.class);

    }

 public static void logData(final String clazz, final String method,final String msg) { 
        logger.info(msg);
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: You said you tried to logging with `this` class, which class do you mean by `this`? You have to include your code in the question. It makes it more clear what are you asking for.

Comment: Can I ask you what's underlying problem are you trying to solve by using this wrapper? Because you're (sort of) re-inventing the wheel. The logger itself provides the same services for you configurable via a simple property file. Maybe by knowing the underlying problem I would be able to give you a better answer

Comment: Thanks @zaerymoghaddam , though it looks like kind of reinventing  , we have some customization within this wrapper class(couldnt include the complete code) , and also we want to avoid the direct interaction of the classes with logging API.

Comment: What's your runtime environment? Is it OK for you to use the CDI API to inject the logger into your classes?

Comment: Its Java 8 , Spring boot

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution,
but you can pull the calling class from the stack and use in the log message.

To do this, you can do something like this:

```
    final StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();
    final Throwable throwable = new Throwable();

    try
    {
        final StackTraceElement[] elements = throwable.getStackTrace();
        final String methodName;

        if ((elements != null) &&
            (elements.length > 2))
        {
            methodName = elements[2].getMethodName();

            returnValue.append(methodName);
            returnValue.append("()");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignoredException)
    {
        // use some default value.
    }

    return returnValue;
```

The index of the desired class may not be 2 for you.

Comment: But this may work if its an exception but it should cover non-exception scenarios as well. I need to log "MyAppLogTest " as the class name when am printing it from the ApplicationLogger class . That way I would be able to log the source class name which is invoking my ApplicatonLogger

Comment: Oops, I re read the code , my bad. But wouldnt it be a overhead to create Throwable for each request especially if the volume is high

Comment: the statement "I want classname automatically in logs" is the same as saying "I don't mind some extra overhead".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a nice and straightforward way to access the name of the method that called the logger. But I think a solution to access the class name of the caller could be something like this (I didn't have time to run it, but I think it would work):

```
class MyAppLogTest {
    //    An static instance of your custom logger initialized with
    //    the class that would call it
    private static ApplicationLogger applicationLogger = new ApplicationLogger(MyAppLogTest.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String msg="Some Msg";
        applicationLogger.logData("main", msg);
    }
}


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class ApplicationLogger {

    private static Logger logger;
    private Class callingClass;

    public ApplicationLogger(Class callingClass) {
        this.callingClass = callingClass;
        this.logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(callingClass);
    }
}

public static void logData(final String method, final String msg) { 
    logger.info(method + "-" + msg);
}
```

}

If it's really important to have also access to the method name, you can add another property of type `Method` to your `ApplicationLogger` class and initialize it in constructor. Then you can instantiate the logger per method (which could easily become a performance bottleneck) and passing your current method as that parameter.

Also I think it worth to take a look at Aspect Oriented Programming techniques/libraries. Maybe you could find another solution based on AOP for your original problem.